# Maven repository manager and SCM systems

Tags: git, maven, version-control, archiva

Using Apache Archiva as a repository manager to control what maven artifacts users download. Want the artifacts managed by Archiva to reside in a SCM system (git) to be able to clearly tag everything that a particular version of the software suite uses. How does one go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

A particular version of your software which has a particular version doesn't need to be tagged in that way, cause the version of your software has a pom.xml which describes all artifacts (also their transitive dependencies) which are needed to rebuilt from scratch. The only thing you need to do is making a backup of your repository manager storage.

Comment: That is certainly one option although I'd rather have everything in one repository and manage all artifacts - code and associated dependent libraries in one way. This is particularly important as you start dealing with may branches, labels and release versions.